# When I try to assert that a function is not called, using mock, why do I get a ``AssertionError: assert None`` error?

Tags: python, mocking, assert

So I am writing some unit tests and I want to test that a certain function is not called.
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
def persist(...): 
    for key, meta in metadata.items(): 
        if key in invalid_currency: 
             continue 

    _get_security_status(...) 

    return 



def test_persist(...): 
    ... 
    exg._meta.metadata = {
                    ('EBBO_0', '20210104'): {'ccy': '', 'mic': 'xswx'},
                    ('EBBO_00', '20210104'): {'ccy': 'GBPO', 'mic': 'xswx'}
                  }

    with patch('exchanges.exchange.Meta._get_security_status') as get_security_status:
        exg._meta.persist(security_files_generated)
        assert get_security_status.assert_not_called()

test_persist()


#AssertionError: assert None
```

So when I run the above, I get a `AssertionError: assert None` error. I expect the test to pass.
When I set a `breakpoint()` inside the `persist` function just above `continue`, in both of the two cases, it hits the `continue` statement, so i know it isn't to do with the data, but rather with how I am mocking or using `assert_not_called()`?

My expectation is that the test case pases, since there is no call to the `get_security_status` function.

Comment: Remove the extra `assert`.  Just do `get_security_status.assert_not_called()`.  The `assert_not_called` function *does* the assert for you, and returns `None` if successful.

Comment: You are a life saver sir. Why does this work?

Comment: Alternatively you could do `assert get_security_status.call_count == 0`.  I usually prefer that over using helpers like `assert_not_called` because if you typo a function name on a mock object you'll just get a mock and your test might "pass" even when it's broken.  :P

Comment: Thank you sir, makes perfect sense.